# How to attach tag to an AWS branch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-codecommit

Is it possible to create an aws tag on a branch in codecommit repository in aws? Or to get the branch owner? 
What I want do achieve is creating a policy that would allow to delete
only branches created by the user that tries to delete them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to create an aws tag on a branch in codecommit repository in aws?

No, you can only tag a Repository.

> Or to get the branch owner?

There is no concept of branch owner in CodeCommit.

> What I want do achieve is creating a policy that would allow to delete only branches created by the user that tries to delete them.

You can achieve this on the Branch level with an IAM conditions like:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "codecommit:DeleteBranch",
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:codecommit:us-east-2:80398EXAMPLE:MyDemoRepo",
            "Condition": {
                            "StringEqualsIfExists": { 
                               "codecommit:References": [ "refs/heads/${aws:username}_*" ] 
                             },
                "Null": {
                    "codecommit:References": false
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

In the above, DeleteBranch is only allowed if the Branch name matches the username. Please see [1] [2] & [3].

[1] https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/refining-access-to-branches-in-aws-codecommit/

[2] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/auth-and-access-control-iam-identity-based-access-control.html

[3] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_variables.html